# Insert a div in random intervals Laravel collection

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel application which is an ecommerce store.

On my shop category which contains rows of products I'd like to randomly in between the products insert a div.

This div should be random throughout the page.

For example, I have the following (I've pruned the code to keep it clean):

```
@section('content')

    <div class="products"> 

    @foreach($page->products->chunk(6) as $chunk)

        <div class="group">

        @foreach($chunk as $product)
            <div class="category_product"> 

                <div class="category_product_info">
                    <h2>
                        <a href="{{ $product->slug->slug }}">
                            {{ $product->title }}
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>

            </div>
        @endforeach

        </div>

    @endforeach

    </div>

@endsection
```

In the chunk of 6 is it possible to inject say a seventh element which would appear randomly on the row?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what information you are trying to add into your 7th div, but here is how I see it: check for each loop if a random between 1 and 100 it higher than your resired random rate ( in my case 50% ) , if so add the div.

```
@section('content')

<div class="products"> 

@foreach($page->products->chunk(6) as $chunk)

    <div class="group">

    @foreach($chunk as $product)
        <div class="category_product"> 

            <div class="category_product_info">
                <h2>
                    <a href="{{ $product->slug->slug }}">
                        {{ $product->title }}
                    </a>
                </h2>
            </div>

        </div>
    @endforeach

    </div>
    @if (rand(1, 100) > 50)
    <div class=randomdiv></div>
    @endif
@endforeach

</div>

@endsection
```

You would apply the same process with your chuck, instead of 6 , add a one line if ( i don't know how they are called ). something like 
`@foreach($page->products->chunk(rand(1, 100) > 50 ? 6 : 7) as $chunk)`